# Bash - Execute two commands and get exit status 1 if first fails

Tags: bash, exit-status

In the case below, the `report` command must always be executed but I need to get an exit status 1 if the `test` command fails:

```
test;report
echo $?
0
```

How can I do it in a single bash line without creating a shell script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Save and reuse `$?`.

```
test; ret=$?; report; exit $ret
```

If you have multiple test commands and you want to run them all, but keep track of whether one has failed, you can use bash's ERR trap.

```
failures=0
trap 'failures=$((failures+1))' ERR
test1
test2
if ((failures == 0)); then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "$failures failures"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

What is a shell script except a file containing shell commands? You could pretend it's not a shell script *and* put it on one line with something like:

```
(test; r=$?; report; [ "$r" -gt 0 ] && exit 1; exit 0)
```

This exits the subshell with a `1` if the first command returned anything other than `0`; otherwise, it returns `0`.

For examples -- I'm just echoing something in lieu of running a real program:

```
$ (false; r=$?; echo report; [ "$r" -gt 0 ] && exit 1; exit 0)
report
$ echo $?
1
$ (true; r=$?; echo report; [ "$r" -gt 0 ] && exit 1; exit 0)
report
$ echo $?
0
$ # example with an exit-status of 2:
$ (grep foo bar; r=$?; echo report; [ "$r" -gt 0 ] && exit 1; exit 0)
grep: bar: No such file or directory
report
$ echo $?
1
```

If you regularly set the `errexit` shell option, you'd want to add in an override so that the subshell doesn't exit prematurely:

```
(set +o errexit; false; r=$?; echo report; [ "$r" -gt 0 ] && exit 1; exit 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You said "exit status 1 if the `test` command fails".  Assuming you intended to make that distinction (i.e., you want the exit value to be 1 even if the `test` command exits with, say, 2, or 3, or whatever), then this is a decent solution:

```
test && { report; true; } || { report; false; }
```

If you did not really mean "1", but whatever non-zero that `test` exited with would be OK as your overall exit code, then the current top answer (save and reuse $?) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A really bad idea, but this seems to work, for some inspiration:

```
(trap report exit; test)
```